# Python-Selenium cant find "id" of button to click

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

This is the "button" I want my code to click, its id as u can see is: "syi-create"
https://gyazo.com/0b03a884cb62227aeebb3dd82b1c67ff

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep



browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/sebastian/desktop/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://www.dba.dk/log-ind/?returnUrl=%2F')

emailStr = "Censored"
passwdStr = "Censored"

def loginDBA(username, password):
    email = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')
    email.send_keys(username)
    adgangskode = browser.find_element_by_id('Password')
    adgangskode.send_keys(password)

    login = browser.find_element_by_id('LoginButton')
    login.click()
loginDBA(emailStr, passwdStr)




opretAnnonce = browser.find_element_by_id("syi-create")
sleep(5)
opretAnnonce.click()
```

Note that you cant run the script, because i "censored" the username and password. So it wont login, but there is no need for that anyways.

When you log in, that yellow button is the one I want to press. But as you might realise, for some reason it doesnt find the button. And therefor cant click it.

Here is the error code (:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"syi-create"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Which very specific says that I cant find the id, which is very wierd since u can see here that I did: https://gyazo.com/0b03a884cb62227aeebb3dd82b1c67ff
Here is another one of me searching for the "id" of the button: 
https://gyazo.com/f4ab86efefc1bc420e71aeca93ed36ca

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's the bet that this is in an iframe?

Comment: I have no experience with web languages by the way, just thought I would say that real quick. And... What is iframe?

Comment: Just looked up iframe, so what you are saying is that I amt trying to click on an image?

Well, first up how can I find the real button id then? And how can I check if its in an iframe?

Comment: Maybe try synchronizing your script and wait for it to appear before clicking on it? While it could be in an iframe/frame, it may just as well be a sync issue

Comment: I thought about that already. I thought a solution to that was to put that "sleep(5)" to w8 for the website to load. before searching for the button to click. as u can see in the 3 last lines of the code above.

Comment: An `IFRAME` is not an image, it's a tag. See if one exists in the HTML above your desired tag. If so, you'll have to switch to the `IFRAME` context before locating the element. There are plenty of guides on how to do that. If not, please provide more info.

Comment: Also, the wait should be before this statement opretAnnonce = browser.find_element_by_id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xpath to find element by id or you can also use

```
sleep(10)
opretAnnonce = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#syi-create")
```

Or

```
sleep(10)
opretAnnonce = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id = "syi-create"]')
```

Comment: It didn't work, I got the same error, now just with an # in front of the id.

Comment: If finding the element by id doesn't work, finding it with an xpath that includes the id won't work either.

Comment: You can use class name to find the element

Comment: Give it a time to load the data use sleep so as the content load properly